# Failure when decompressing gzip file with Python

Tags: python, file, gzip, gunzip

I've downloaded a *"myfile.tsv.gz"* file from Azure (with *azcopy*). I want to open it in Python.

```
import gzip
f = gzip.open('myfile.tsv.gz', 'rb')
file_content = f.read()
```

But with both Python 2.7.16 and Python 3.9.5 on macOs, I got the error message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python@3.9/3.9.5/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/gzip.py", line 300, in read
    return self._buffer.read(size)
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python@3.9/3.9.5/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/gzip.py", line 495, in read
    uncompress = self._decompressor.decompress(buf, size)
zlib.error: Error -3 while decompressing data: invalid block type
```

I really don't have idea how I could fix it.

FYI, on my terminal this command yields:

```
>gunzip -t myfile.tsv.gz

gunzip: data stream error 
gunzip: myfile.tsv.gz: uncompress failed
```

Nevertheless this command seems to print correctly the file content:

```
>gunzip -c myfile.tsv.gz

[correct file content]
```

I've also tried to re-download this file, same issue...

Thanks!

Comment: Probably something wrong with the file then, no?

Comment: The file is corrupted. You need to go to whomever this file came from for help.

Comment: Just because the data that can be read _before_ you hit the corrupt bits is all the data you need/want doesn't mean the file isn't corrupt; it just means it might be corrupt in a way you don't care about. Still, it would be bad practice to write code that ignored errors just because this one time you didn't care about the error.

Comment: BTW, what does `gunzip -c <myfile.tsv.gz >/dev/null; echo "Exit status: $?"` yield?

Comment: Thanks for your help.
Here is the command output:

`>gunzip -c <myfile.tsv.gz >/dev/null; echo "Exit status: $?"
gunzip: data stream error
Exit status: 1`